# Shell string manipulation, wildcard scope

Tags: string, shell, replace

I am attempting to manipulate a string in shell by removing a substring, separated by some delimiters. Currently I am having some undesired behavior from the wildcard character as follows:

```
string='start.badstuff.goodstuff.end'
echo ${string/bad*.}    #start.end
```

In the above example say I know the substring I seek to remove starts with `'bad'` followed by random `'stuff.'` all of which I wish to remove. I want to keep the string `'goodstuff'`, however, in this example the wildcard takes the widest scope instead of the narrowest (taking `*='stuff.goodstuff'` instead of the desired behavoir `*='stuff'`).

Is there a way to limit the scope of the wildcard to stop at the first `'.'` after `'badstuff'`, without knowing what `'goodstuff'` might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enabled ext. glob (see on this [page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) for details)

`shopt -s extglob`

you could do

```
echo ${string/bad*([^.]).}
```

which results in

```
start.goodstuff.end
```